# Easy C++ = array length and reverse WITHOUT <string>

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can't seem to get my array's length or to print backwards! ANY HELP PLEASE?!
the functions on the bottom for void GetStringLenght and Print Backwards aren't working

```
#include <iostream>

void ReadString(char* c, int maxLength);

void GetStringLength(char* c, int* length);

void PrintString(char* const c);

void PrintStringBackwards(char* const c);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 50;
    char ca[SIZE];
    char* pc = ca;
    int fPrints = 0;
    int bPrints = 0;
    int lengthChecks = 0;

    char selection = 'z';
    while (selection != 'Q') {
        std::cout << "\n[ 1] Test ReadString\n";
        std::cout << "[ 2] Test GetStringLength\n";
        std::cout << "[ 3] Test PrintString\n";
        std::cout << "[ 4] Test PrintStringBackwards\n";
        std::cout << "[Q] Quit\n";
        std::cout << "Selection: ";
        std::cin >> selection;
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cout << std::endl;

        switch (selection) {
        //Test ReadString
        case '1':
            ReadString(pc, SIZE);
            break;
        //Test GetStringLength
        case '2': {
            lengthChecks += 1;
            int length = 0;
            GetStringLength(pc, &length);
            std::cout << "Length[" << lengthChecks << "]=" << length << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        //Test PrintString
        case '3':
            fPrints += 1;
            std::cout << "Foward[" << fPrints << "]=";
            PrintString(pc);
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        //[ 4] Test PrintStringBackwards
        case '4':
            bPrints += 1;
            std::cout << "Backwards[" << bPrints << "]=";
            PrintStringBackwards(pc);
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;

        case 'Q':
            break;
        default:
            break;
        } //end switch

    } //end while
    std::cout << "Press ENTER";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void ReadString(char* c, int maxLength)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a string less than " << maxLength << " characters." << std::endl;

    std::cin.getline(c, maxLength, '\n');
}

//BELOW THIS DOESNT WORK EITHER///
//////////////////////////////////////////
void GetStringLength(char* c, int* length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *length; i++) {
        if (c[i] == '\0')
            *length = i - 1;
    }
}

void PrintString(char* const c)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (c[i] == '\0') {
            counter = i;
            break;
        } //end if
    } //end for
    for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
        std::cout << c[j];
        if (j == counter)
            std::cout << '\0';
    } //end for
    std::cout << std::endl;
} //end void

void PrintStringBackwards(char* const c)
{
    //this is where I’m lost! I’ve tried 25 different ways and everything is error.
}
```

Comment: Run a reverse for loop

Comment: Is this your real code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes I just really need help with my homework

Comment: @SUZYislost Well, that doesn't compile.

Comment: is it forbidden to use `std::string`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes unfortunately

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's not compiling because there's nothing in the last function of void PrintStringBackwards

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal thank you! i will try that for backwards but any tips on how to get length?

Comment: @SUZYislost No, it doesn't compile, because `include iostream` gives you a syntax error.

Comment: I fixed that. I assume that was part of a bad copy / paste.

Comment: Sooner or later you will need to learn to use the debugger. But to get you started in the right direction, what is the value of *length when GetStringLength is first called? Will the for loop execute at all? Since you don't know the length of the string, wouldn't a while loop be better?

Comment: @SUZYislost If the issue is printing a string backwards, why are you posting menu code, and other unrelated items?  Just a simple `main()` that calls the PrintBackwards function is all you need to show us.

Comment: @SUZYislost *but any tips on how to get length* -- You use `strlen`.  If you say you can't even use `strlen`, then the course you're taking is a joke (just not being able to use `std::string` is bad enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `for (int i = 0; i < *length; i++)` where both `i` and `*length` are `0`, as in your case... will that loop ever execute? Nope... Consider a loop that starts with `x` set to `0` and `return x;` when `str[x]` is `'\0'`. i.e. the loop in `strlen` does this.

As for printing backwards, start at the highest index (returned by `strlen` or your function once fixed) and decrement until you reach `0`, printing the characters at those offsets as you go.

`strlen` is available in `<cstring>`, by the way, not just `<string>`... and as it is a mandatory function it'll always be part of any C++ implementation. You should probably just use `strlen`...

Answer (score 0):

To get a C string (`char*`)'s length you can use `strlen(...)`.
To print backwards, do:

```
for(int i = strlen(str) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    std::cout << str[i];
```